# Switching views in iOS

Tags: iphone, view, navigation

I have 3 view controllers in my storyboard for example `Page1`, `Page2`, and `Page3`. Both `Page1` and `Page2` are pushed to `Page3`. What I want to do is when `Page3`tap on Back button, the view will 100% return to `Page1` and never get back to `Page2`. The code I am using now is

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

What will go back to the page it comes from is there any way to do that? I want to fix the page it back but not pop back to where it comes from.

Comment: you should use the `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:true]`, if the _Page1_ is the root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use the

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:true];
```

it will work for you perfectly, if the *Page1* is the root.

Answer (score 0):

You should create Custom Navigation Controller with back button on it and on click of back button write my code for navigating to a `page 1`

drag a navigation bar in `.xib` file and put a back button on it,

code snippet on back button,

```
-(void)BackButtonClick
{
  YourView *Obj = [[YourView alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourView" bundle:nil];
  [self.navigationController popViewController:Obj animated:YES];
  [Obj release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
- (NSArray *)popToViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated

 NSInteger currentIndex = [self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self];
if( currentIndex-2 >= 0 ) 
{
   [self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:currentIndex-2] animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: what does happen when `currentIndex < 2`? will the user be stuck?